# TortoiseGit / Browse References: What does the Current Branch button do?

Tags: tortoisegit

Seems to just exit the dialog.  Help doesn't say anything about it. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Browse References dialog is used to select a reference, the button is a shortcut to select the current branch. - If the browse references dialog is not opened for selection, the button just closes the dialog.